# How to setup elastic inference combined with an EC2 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, inference

I just found out about the new AWS elastic inference to make access and use of Teraflops cheaper. I found it unbelieavably complex to understand what the [intro page is talking about](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-inference.html), especially the part where they explain what needs to be done in order to have it set up and running. Until now I just have been using p2xlarge instances to run deep learning training and inference.
I am mostly interested in to combining an EC2 c4.xlarge or a c5.xlarge with the eia1.large

Did anybody go through the steps already? is there a full tutorial on how to do that step by step on that context. Unfortunately the current "tutorial" just points to other tutorials that are too general.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling at the beginning too getting errors when trying to run their example but eventually I managed. Here's where you should start and I can not emphasize the importance of following the instructions on this page in detail more :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/setting-up-ei.html

very very important and complete set of instructions. Pay attention to all inbound and outbound rules and different security group settings.

then simply follow this example and take it from there :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-tf-elastic-inference.html

Good luck!

P.s. my instance setup was c5.xlarge + eia1.medium